# how to get Outline from BitmapDrawable, or at least is it possible?

Tags: android

I simply want to make drop-shadow from ImageView's drawable using setElevation which has unique form.
As i understand i simply have to set View's outline, so how to get the Outline from drawable?
I tried doing it so, but it doesn't give any kind of shadow:

```
 Outline outline = new Outline();
 image.getDrawable().getOutline(outline);
 image.setOutlineProvider(new ViewOutlineProvider() {
     @Override
     public void getOutline(View view, Outline outline) {
         outline.set(outline);
     }
 });
```

and xml:

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/image"
    android:elevation="8dp"
    android:layout_width="48dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:adjustViewBounds="false"
    android:hapticFeedbackEnabled="true"
    android:scaleType="centerInside"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_drawable" />
```

Comment: You might want to have a look at this tutorial: http://www.coderzheaven.com/2012/01/08/create-image-reflection-android/ - It's a reflection, but wit a small effort you can make it black and turn it to a shadow.

Answer (score 0):

As far as creating shadow is concerned, you can create a 9-patch image for shadow, set it as background of the image view and you actual drawable as it source using 
`android:src`

Then just provide padding to the different sides so that for that amount, background is visible that will act as shadow.